# Problem with Jenkins url encoding of env.BUILD_URL in groovy script

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, groovy

The valid Jenkins-URL shown in the browser is: (note the **%2F**!)

```
http://my-server/job/test_repo/job/testing%2Fbranch/1/
```

When I pass `env.BUILD_URL` to a `bat ( script: "script.py -url " + env.BUILD_URL")` in my groovy file, the url I receive inside the script is: (note the **52F**!)

```
http://my-server/job/test_repo/job/testing52Fbranch/1/
```

Is there a way to resolve this URL encoding/escaping problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` character must be escaped by duplicating it:

```
bat ( script: "script.py -url " + env.BUILD_URL.replace('%','%%') )
```

Comment: It helped to escape base 64 encoded special character %. Thanks